# Unit tests for Gridgain Client

Tags: maven, ignite, gridgain

Can I know a method to implement unit test for Gridgain client written in maven project as thick client. Need to test SQL, Transactions, locking and other basic APIs of cache features in unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

You can start multiple nodes within the same JVM and form a cluster, then test any functionality, it will behave like a real cluster (because it is).

```java
IgniteConfiguration serverCfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
        .setIgniteInstanceName("server")
        .setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi()
                .setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder()
                        .setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47503"))));

Ignite server = Ignition.start(serverCfg);

IgniteConfiguration clientCfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
        .setIgniteInstanceName("client")
        .setClientMode(true)
        .setDiscoverySpi(new TcpDiscoverySpi()
                .setIpFinder(new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder()
                        .setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47503"))));

Ignite client = Ignition.start(clientCfg);

client.getOrCreateCache("c").put(1, "Hello");
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. My actual server and client running in Google Kubernetes engine. It use TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder to discovery. How I address this.

Comment: @NuwanSameera You don't need GKE for unit tests. Write your test logic with in-process nodes as explained above to verify the desired behavior.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much